# Change xml bar in runtime

Tags: java, android, xml, colors, runtime

I wish to change my `app:footercolor` value defined on xml file, and I want to do this while runtime.

How can I achieve this? I haven't found any information about how to do this. I'm find very hard to learn something just about changing xml through java. I'm certain that there must be a way to make that happen and I just can't figure it out.

Here is the xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"

        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:background="#000000"    
        android:textColor="#1573D6"
        app:footerColor="#1573D6"

        app:footerLineHeight="2dp"
        app:footerIndicatorStyle="none"

        app:selectedColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:selectedBold="true" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you please paste the entire contents of the XML file? Ie the file that contains `app:footercolor` ?

Comment: Sure, it is there now; I edited the question. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

The XML definitions will get turned into Java Objects when the activity is launched. So what you need to do is to get a reference to those Java objects and change them - instead of trying to modify the XML.

I'm not very familiar with Android, but I *think* the following will work:

```
TitlePageIndicator titleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
int blue = 0xFF;
titleIndicator.setFooterColor(blue);
titleIndicator.invalidate(); // get the UI to repaint this View at some point
```

Let me know how it goes!